# E: The package poppler-utils needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt

I keep on receiving this message when ever i use apt-get but I cant update the packages as this message pops up please help.

In reply to @Jos
The results of `apt policy poppler-*`

```
> poppler-utils:
  Installed: 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5
  Candidate: 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5
  Version table:
 *** 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.41.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
poppler-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.41.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.41.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
poppler-data:
  Installed: 0.4.7-7
  Candidate: 0.4.7-7
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.7-7 500
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If i try `sudo apt install --reinstall poppler-utils

```
>justin@HomePc:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall poppler-utils
 [sudo] password for justin: 
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree        
 Reading state information... Done
 E: The package poppler-utils needs to be reinstalled, but I can't 
 find an archive for it.
```

The output `sudo dpkg --configure poppler-utils`

`

```
> justin@HomePc:~$ sudo dpkg --configure poppler-utils
  [sudo] password for justin: 
  dpkg: error processing package poppler-utils (--configure):
  package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
  reinstall it before attempting configuration
  Errors were encountered while processing:
  poppler-utils
```

Comment: Should be in the normal repos. What does `apt policy poppler-*` tell you?

Comment: @Jos edited it what do you think now

Comment: What is the exact error message you get if you do `sudo apt install --reinstall poppler-utils`?

Comment: @Jos added in the error code

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg --configure poppler-utils` and add the output to your question, if it is informative at all

Comment: Could be a simple case of being unable to reach the server. Can you ping za.archive.ubuntu.com?

Comment: @Jos I can ping the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some files had been moved to another partition on another disk while dual booting after removing the other disk I was able to Install stuff.